# How to install pysndfile via pip on windows?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on audio classification by using tensorflow in python. I have got a code which needs to import pysndfile but I can't install it using pip because of my os is Windows 10. Is there another option to install it? or Is there another similar library for Windows os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'pysndfile' is not supported on the Windows platform ref.[this link](https://forge-2.ircam.fr/roebel/pysndfile). If you want to use it on windows you need to install [docker](https://www.docker.com/) to handle Linux environment.